# Why isn't this variable defined through closure?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple JS code like the following. When I click on the `h2` element, I get a reference error saying that `h2Elements is not defined` on the `console.log('h2Elements', h2Elements)` when `console.log('faqs', faqs)` works fine.

Shouldn't `h2Elements` be defined like `faqs` is through closure?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <main id="faqs">
        <h2><a href="#" >What is JavaScript?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>JavaScript is a programming language that's built into the major web browsers.
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>
      var toggle = function() {
        console.log('faqs', faqs)
        console.log('h2Elements', h2Elements)
      };

      window.onload = function() {
          var faqs = document.getElementById("faqs");
          var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");

          for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++ ) {
            h2Elements[i].onclick = toggle;
          }
      };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `toggle` method doesn't have the visibility to `h2Elements`.

Comment: where have you given id as `h2Elements`  to any tag in html body?

Comment: `faqs` is not defined through closure, it's defined because [it has the same name as the id in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables).

Comment: I believe getElementsByTagName returns a collection not an element reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faqs and h2Elements are not in scope of toggle function. faqs variable inside toggle function is giving output because 'faqs' is id of some DOM element.